# 'genObjectName' Not Creating a Valid TextureObject

Tags: opengl, haskell

I'm attempting to write a test in Haskell to load a texture into OpenGL and render it on a screen. I loaded (or so I thought) everything into my program, but when I rendered the texture, it came up as a white block. Upon looking this up, I found that it could be due to the `TextureObject` being invalid. So I added a test to find out:

```
t <- genObjectName

isobj <- isObjectName t
if not isobj
  then error "Could not bind object name."
  else do
    ...
```

Whenever I run the program, I get an `error "Could not bind object name."`, without fail.

Does `genObjectName` work differently than I think it does? Do I have to perform more on the `TextureObject` before I can check if it exists? (I've also tried using `genObjectNames 1`, but I doubt that would function any differently than `genObjectName`.)

I'm running `OpenGL-2.9.2.0`, under `GHC-7.8.3`, and `base-4.7.0.1`.

Comment: Do you have a valid OpenGL context? You can figure out why your function call is failing by calling `GL.get GL.errors`

Comment: Those results are actually what you should expect. You need to bind an OpenGL (texture) object at least once before it becomes a valid object. It is basically a reserved name up until you first bind it, and then after it is bound it is allocated state and such (becomes an instantiated object in other words).

Comment: I'd write that as an answer, except I am not quite sure how these function names correlate to actual OpenGL API calls :-\

Answer (score 2):

Based on the feedback from Andon M. Coleman, the [associated C GL API](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-2.9.1.0/docs/src/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Texturing-TextureObject.html#TextureObject) calls you're making are:

```
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
if (!glIsTexture(tex)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind object name.\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

According to the [man pages](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glIsTexture.xml) for `glIsTexture`:

```
A name returned by glGenTextures, but not yet associated with a texture by calling glBindTexture, is not the name of a texture.
```

Answer (score -1):

In OpenGL 2.9, you don't use `genObjectName`/`genObjectNames` as much. Most places it was used before it is no longer correct. Unfortunantely, the breaking changes to the API for the OpenGL Haskell binding for 2.9 aren't documented anywhere that I've found.

For example, for shaders, before 2.9 you would have written something like:

```
createVertexShader :: Shader s => String -> IO s
createVertexShader source =
    do
        [s] <- genObjectNames 1
        shaderSource s $= [source]
        compileShader s
        return s
```

You now don't use `genObjectNames` at all, instead you call `createShader`.

```
createVertexShader:: String -> IO Shader
createVertexShader source =
    do
        s <- createShader VertexShader
        shaderSource s $= [source]
        compileShader s
        return s
```

For programs, you don't use `genObjectNames`, you use `createProgram`.

For textures, you still use `genObjectNames` with e.g. `textureBinding`